# Converting string to float . Programming

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to read a text file that contains a lot of values. So first I append all the values to my list and my task is to find the sum of these values.

While appending I do something like: `lst.append(float(values))`.

I get an error since there are alphabetical strings like `DNE` in the values list.

So if `value == 'DNE'` how do I ignore that and let the program only focus on float values and add it.

For adding I know it's `sum(lst)`, just wanted to know how to ignore that `'DNE'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to convert a string to a numeric value you'll get a [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) exception because that is not allowed.
You need to wrap your `append()` call in a [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) block to catch these errors and handle them in an appropriate way:

A simple block of:

```
try:
    lst.append(float(value))
except ValueError:
    print "Cannot convert String to Float!"
```

should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `try/except` and ignore the specific exception raised when the value can not be converted to a float:

```
try:
    lst.append(float(values))
except ValueError as exc:
    pass
```